# Alternate of IN operator or Replace IN operator from function in query?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a query and i need the same 
without using the IN operator

here is query

```
  create function registerStudent(
      in s_id varchar(5),
      in s_courseid varchar (8), 
      in s_secid varchar (8),
      in semester varchar (6), 
      in s_year numeric (4,0),
      out errorMsg varchar(100) returns integer 
      begin 
           declare currEnrol int; 
           select count(*) into currEnrol from takes
           where course_id = s_courseid 
           and secid = s_secid 
           and semester = s_semester 
           and year = s_year; 

           declare limit int; 
           select capacity into limit 
           from classroom 
           natural join section 
           where course_id = s_courseid 
           and secid = s_secid 
           and semester = s_semester 
           and year = s_year; 

           if (currEnrol < limit) begin 
               insert into takes values  (s_id, s_courseid, s_secid, s_semester, s_year, null); 
               return(0); 
           end

          set errorMsg = 'Enrollment limit reached for course ' I I s_courseid II ' section ' I I s_secid; 
          return(-1); 
      end;
```

Comment: where have you used IN operator?

Comment: NEAR CRAETE FUNCTION

Comment: in s_id varchar(5), ETC

Comment: you can write parameter without `in`

Comment: oh that work are you sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you list all parameters of the stored function inside the parentheses. By default, all parameters are `IN` parameters. You cannot specify `IN , OUT or INOUT` modifiers to the parameters.

```
create function registerStudent(
      s_id varchar(5),
      s_courseid varchar (8), 
      s_secid varchar (8),
      semester varchar (6), 
      s_year numeric (4,0),
      out errorMsg varchar(100)
      ) returns integer 
      begin 
           declare currEnrol int; 
           select count(*) into currEnrol from takes
           where course_id = s_courseid 
           and secid = s_secid 
           and semester = s_semester 
           and year = s_year; 

       declare limit int; 
       select capacity into limit 
       from classroom 
       natural join section 
       where course_id = s_courseid 
       and secid = s_secid 
       and semester = s_semester 
       and year = s_year; 

       if (currEnrol < limit) begin 
           insert into takes values  (s_id, s_courseid, s_secid, s_semester, s_year, null); 
           return(0); 
       end

      set errorMsg = 'Enrollment limit reached for course ' I I s_courseid II ' section ' I I s_secid; 
      return(-1); 
  end;
```